# serverside browser animation render and save as video

Tags: node.js, server-side-rendering, server-side, cesiumjs

i created an animation drawing a route with cesium.I need to get the video by taking a screen recording of the html page where the animation is running.  I'm trying to convert the animation to video by rendering the browser on the server side. What kind of path should I follow?

I am expecting to create video from this animation. I find ffmpeg and puppeteer.I searched but there weren't enough resources for me to understand so I couldn't put information together.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.